# Java Database with Mapping?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, dictionary, mapping

I am going to make a database where I need to make use of mapping, (THIS IS NOT JAVA EE) I am speaking of JavaSE only not EE, I was wondering how would I implement these class I made? (User,Contactinformation,Employee,FinanceTeam,SystemAdmin) how will I transfer the datas of these objects into the database? and how does mapping work? a BASIC Database tutorial will HELP me a lot, Thanks Btw if you are curious I am using MySQL for my database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) and Hibernate is the most commonly used, Hibernate can also be used standalone, not only in Java EE environment.

- [The official tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html)
- [JavaBrains Hibernate Tutorial](http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/hibernate.html)

JavaBrains video tutorial is 34 lessons, well explained and easy to understand, I highly recommend you. The author is not a native English speaker, so if you look past the accent, it's a great content.

Comment: if I am doing it standlone, is there any difference? within the code or none?

Comment: The only difference is how you obtain the EntityManager, as @SplinterReality showed you. The Entity manager is the object that will help you persist your objects.

Comment: The POJO (Plain Old Java Object), that you want to persist, and as such, you should annotate it with @Entity at the class level... it will all clear up as you work through the tutorials...

Comment: with hibernate, the details in my setters and getters will be in the database?????

Comment: Once you add an `@Entity` annotation on the class and an `@Id` annotation on the primary key field, or getter, the other fields or getters will be persisted, except those annotated with `@Transient` (or preceded with the `transient` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a JPA like Hibernate or EclipseLink?  They work just fine in a J2SE environment, the only difference is how you obtain the EntityManager reference. (By creating the EntityManagerFactory directly as opposed to Container Managed Injection)

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: I don't have any idea about Persistence API ,  I don't know how to use them I have no idea at all